# Laravel 5.3 api form validation

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

In Laravel 5.2 I could validate a `request` by making a Request class (`php artisan make:request UserStoreRequest`)

Then in my controller I could do:

```
public function store(UserStoreRequest $request)
{
   //logic
}
```

And if one of the rules in my `UserStoreRequest` failed I received something like this back:

```
{
  "error": {
    "email": [
      "The email has already been taken."
    ]
  }
}
```

But if I do exactly the same in `Laravel 5.3` I receive:

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
```

It looks like it looks in my `web.php` instead of `api.php`.

Also in `Laravel 5.3` `UserStoreRequest`

`extends FormRequest`
`(use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;)`

And in `Laravel 5.2` `UserStoreRequest`

`extends Request`

`(use App\Http\Requests\Request;)`

How can I get it to work again!!!
(I've tested this with a fresh install of `Laravel 5.3`)

**ROUTES:**

```
   | POST      | api/login                                     |              | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@login    | api        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/register/{user}/verify/{ConformationCode} |              | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AdminController@confirm | api        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/user                                      | user.index   | App\Http\Controllers\User\UserController@index    | api,active |
|        | POST      | api/user                                      | user.store   | App\Http\Controllers\User\UserController@store    | api,active |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/user/create                               | user.create  | App\Http\Controllers\User\UserController@create   | api,active |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/user/{user}                               | user.show    | App\Http\Controllers\User\UserController@show     | api,active |
|        | PUT|PATCH | api/user/{user}                               | user.update  | App\Http\Controllers\User\UserController@update   | api,active |
|        | DELETE    | api/user/{user}                               | user.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\User\UserController@destroy  | api,active |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/user/{user}/edit                          | user.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\User\UserController@edit     | api,active
```

Comment: Are your routes properly defined?, NotFoundHttpException means that it didnt find a route for the request

Comment: Yes, Please see my edit. I'm making a post request to `api/user/create` Here I'm using the request class `UserStoreRequest`.

Comment: your `api.create` route is a `GET` route, not a `POST` route, thats why you get the exception, i think your post should go to `api.store` instead of `api.create` :)

Comment: Sorry I'm making a `post` request to`api/user` so that cannot be the problem.

Comment: I'm trying this with a fresh install. Very strange!?!

Comment: hmm.. I think there is something wrong within your route ? if is form request issue it wouldn't show this error message